# Grouping in xslt table

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I'm transforming the xml into the xslt but got stuck while grouping the same values in the table. The transformation got successful But What I need is if the ProductName is same or the ItemNumber is same then I don't want to create the header in table. I'm trying to use the variable to determine whether this Item got processed or not But I think i'm missing something in syntax. Here is the code.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Items>
      <Item ItemNumber="1151464">
        <ProductName>Spritz Grape Seat and Extra Seat</ProductName>
        <ProviderName>Bambeano</ProviderName>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <Price>56.99</Price>
      </Item>
      <Item ItemNumber="1150173">
        <ProductName>Lucille Tan</ProductName>
        <ProviderName>Boston Babes</ProviderName>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <Price>24.99</Price>
      </Item>
      <Item ItemNumber="1151464">
        <ProductName>Spritz Grape Seat and Extra Seat</ProductName>
        <ProviderName>Bambeano</ProviderName>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <Price>56.99</Price>
      </Item>
      <Item ItemNumber="1151464">
        <ProductName>Spritz Grape Seat and Extra Seat</ProductName>
        <ProviderName>Bambeano</ProviderName>
        <Quantity>20</Quantity>
        <Price>56.99</Price>
      </Item>
      <Item ItemNumber="1151464">
        <ProductName>Spritz Grape Seat and Extra Seat</ProductName>
        <ProviderName>Bambeano</ProviderName>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <Price>56.99</Price>
      </Item>
      <Item ItemNumber="1251464">
        <ProductName>Apple Pattern T-Shirt-Blue</ProductName>
        <ProviderName>Avahna</ProviderName>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <Price>14.99</Price>
      </Item>
</Items>
```

Here in the above code I have the ProductName "`Spritz Grape Seat and Extra Seat`" more than one time. Currently my xslt prints it separately. I need to be in group like the following output.

[image: Output]

as well as the Grand-total of the all the items in the last. Is there any element through which I determine it is the last index of my array or xml ? so that I have add it in temporary variable and sum all of them and at last displayed it?

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
<h1>Sale amount by provider</h1>
    <xsl:for-each select="Items/Item" group-by="@ProductName"> // i tried this something like this
<xsl:sort select="ProductName"/>
    <table border="2" width = "500">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <td colspan="4">Provider: <xsl:value-of select="ProductName"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Item Number</td>
<td>Quantity</td>
<td>Unit Price</td>
<td>Total</td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@ItemNumber"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Quantity"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Price"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Quantity * Price"/></td>
      </tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" align="right"><b>Sub-Total</b></td>
 <td><xsl:value-of select="Quantity * Price"/></td>
</tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
<h1>test</h1>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**What my xslt is reproducing**

[image: Output]

need to be merge in single table

Thanks help will be Appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have tagged this `xslt-2.0` so you can use `xsl:for-each-group` here to do the grouping.

```
 <xsl:for-each-group select="Items/Item" group-by="ProductName">
```

In this you would then do the header for each table. Then, to get the items each group, you can use `current-group()`

```
<xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
```

Where you then output a row for each item in the group

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h1>Sale amount by provider</h1>
  <xsl:for-each-group select="Items/Item" group-by="ProductName">
  <xsl:sort select="ProductName"/>
    <table border="2" width = "500">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <td colspan="4">Provider: <xsl:value-of select="ProductName"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Item Number</td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td>Unit Price</td>
        <td>Total</td>
     </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
     <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@ItemNumber"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Quantity"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Price"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Quantity * Price"/></td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="3" align="right"><b>Sub-Total</b></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/(Quantity * Price))"/></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
</xsl:for-each-group>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It works thanks again and you didn't tell me about the grand total. Should I need to initiate the param or variable to add all the sub-totals or is there any best approach to do that thing? As it's mentioned in the above image. Grand total is actually the sub-total of each

Comment: @MuneebAmjad - After the last `tr` (sub total), add an `xsl:if` with the test `position()=last()`. Inside the `xsl:if`, add the new `tr` for grand total. You can get the grand total value using `<xsl:value-of select="sum(/Items/Item/(Price * Quantity))"/>`.